# How to boot from ISO without USB stick or DVD on Mac OS X 10.4.11 Tiger

Tags: mac, startup, macos, iso

I would like to know a way to boot from an ISO disk image on my iMac running MacOS X Tiger. I DON'T want to use a USB stick or a DVD. Is this possible?

Comment: This appears to be a [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). There is probably a way to boot from a dmg/iso: the Recovery HD of newer Macs work like this. On an older Mac it would require access to some source code and to modify the code for boot.efi there. It doesn't make much sense to store a dmg on an HDD, mount it and boot from it, instead of directly saving the **content** of the dmg to a HDD volume and booting into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's technically possible if you have your hard drive partitioned with the ISO on said partition (and made bootable of course). Otherwise, you'll need to use a USB or disk in order to boot it. If you go with the first option, you can use either Disk Utility or Terminal. This should help if you're using Terminal: http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/13/burn-an-iso-image-from-the-command-line/